# Unable to remove large tarballs from my Git Repo history (via git filter-branch)

Tags: git, github

The following tarballs:

```
./resources/godot.tar.gz
./resources/godot-haskell-gdwlroots.tar.gz
```

have been making my git repo ridiculously large (i.e., 150MB+). I tried moving them with the following command:

```sh
pruneTarballs() {
  git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch ./resources/godot-haskell-gdwlroots.tar.gz" HEAD
  git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch ./resources/godot.tar.gz" HEAD

  git push origin --all --force
  git push origin --tags --force
}
```

but it had no non-trivial effect on the repo's size (still over 150MB)! I then ran:

```sh
# Ensure all old refs are fully removed
rm -Rf .git/logs .git/refs/original

# Perform a garbage collection to remove commits with no refs
git gc --prune=all --aggressive
```

and it also didn't bring the size down below 150MB. For reference, here is the current distribution of the repo:

```sh
$ du -sch .[!.]* * | sort -h
4.0K  Consent.md
4.0K  default_env.tres
4.0K  export_presets.cfg
4.0K  .gitignore
4.0K  .gitmodules
4.0K  icon.png
4.0K  icon.png.import
4.0K  Makefile
4.0K  project.godot
8.0K  README.org
16K   utils
2.3M  doc
3.0M  addons
154M  .git
159M  total
```

---

**EDIT:** I then ran (from [CHECKLIST FOR SHRINKING A RESPOSITORY](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_checklist_for_shrinking_a_repository)):

```sh
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

and now the size of `.git` is 65MB (which still seems very high but much lower than the original 150MB). The CHECKLIST FOR SHRINKING A REPOSITORY also recommended:

> use `--tag-name-filter cat -- --all` when calling git-filter-branch

But it's not clear how to modify my original command filter-branch commands accordingly:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch ./resources/godot-haskell-gdwlroots.tar.gz" HEAD
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch ./resources/godot.tar.gz" HEAD
```

I also ran (per the recommendation of the CHECKLIST):

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d # This parsed as an incorrect command by git
```

but it was parsed as an incorrect command by git so didn't do anything. Does anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT 2:** Now, after making a commit and trying to push to GitHub, I get:

```
$ git push origin --all --force
Enumerating objects: 9, done.
Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 446 bytes | 446.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/gdwlroots
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: 
remote: You can set the 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable
remote: to 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: other way.
remote: 
remote: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To /home/george/./SimulaMakeGit
 ! [remote rejected] gdwlroots -> gdwlroots (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to '/path/to/my/repo.git'
```

Comment: Sanity check: did you `git rm` or `git rm --cached` the two large files? "resources" does not appear in the output of your `du` command, but nothing in your post explicitly deleted it.

Comment: After running `git filter-branch`, see the section titled CHECKLIST FOR SHRINKING A REPOSITORY in [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch). The `rm -rf` you ran on `.git/logs` and `.git/refs/original` *may* have been sufficient, but maybe not.

Comment: @TrevorKeller: My `git filter-branch ..` command ran `git rm --cached` on the resources files, no?

Comment: @torek: I ran some commands from the CHECKLIST you posted and it partially helped. I edited my question above.